# What are the odds of guessing a 4 digit number if told how many you have correct?

Tags: probability

I pick a 4 digit number and you have to guess it exactly right in the right order. If I tell you how many digits you have right, but NOT which one... how many guesses on average should it take?

For example: my number is 4382. And you guess 5309. You have 1 digit right. But you don't know which one.

What about if I tell you a specific digit is correct?

Comment: "How many guesses on average should it take?"  Using what strategy?  The "optimum" strategy?  How do we define optimum here?  The strategy that will take the fewest guesses on *average*?  Or the strategy that will take the fewest guesses in the worst case scenario?

Comment: Related: [Mastermind Five-guess algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Five-guess_algorithm).  This differs from Mastermind in that you have effectively "ten" colors rather than the usual six, and that you only tell us number of digits matching exact location, effectively only giving us "black" responses as opposed to white as well.

Comment: Yes, optimum. Obviously you could get lucky and guess 3 of the 4 on guess 1. But that's unlikely.

Comment: You seem to have stopped reading my question asking for clarification after the second sentence... please read the rest of my question.  You still haven't defined the strategy you are using, and if you are leaving it to us to define that makes it incredibly difficult to answer as it first requires proving that our proposed strategy really is the optimal one.

Comment: Clarify your question.  What if you secretly choose $5512$ and I guess $5346$?  How many digits would you say I have right?  What if you secretly choose $5555$ and I guess $2345$?

Comment: David, I believe it is clear that in both instances he would say you have 1 digit correct, because his set of digits was {3,4,5,6} and the set you chose was {1,2,5,5} so they overlap on a single element.

Comment: You say "yes optimum", but JMoravitz clearly is asking what you mean by optimum. There is optimum on average and optimum worst case (I imagine there are other types, but these are the most common ones people refer to).

Answer (score 1):

For any 4 digit sequence, assuming that 0000 is a valid sequence for the number guessing game that you have devised, it will take a maximum of 34 appropriate guesses to correctly choose the number that you picked, and the number of guesses should be adjusted accordingly.

Methodology:
Guessing the unique number sequences; 0000, 1111, 2222, ... 9999 (10 initial guesses)
This should give you the number of each digit that occurs in the sequence and maximum guesses could only occur for a standardized guessing for a sequence containing a 9.
Then, when you have the numbers available for the sequence (4 total), they can only be arranged in 4! different orders; 0123, 0132, 0213, 0231, 0321, 0312, ... 3210

10 + 4! = 10 + 4*3*2*1 = 34.

Now, the probability of guessing any individual number is 1:10, and the odds of guessing the right number is still 1:10,000 simply based on probability. However, "guessing" in the right manner narrows down the individual probability to 1:34.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Method:Guess 0000,1111,2222,... 8888 (you don't need to guess 9999, because you know the remaining digits must be 9s), slotting in correct digits as you go (e.g. if you found out 0 were one of the digits in your first guess, your next guess would be 0111). Then once you have the 4 correct digits, just go through all the possible orderings.

Worst Case: 33 Guesses (9 in phase 1, 24 in phase 2)

Average Case: 15.72 Guesses

---

Long answer and explanation:

Using Cryostasys's method (guess 0000, 1111, ...  until you figure out the 4 digits; then randomly guess an ordering for the 4 digits). Let's consider 4 cases:

4 unique digits  (e.g. 1234)- to caclulate the probability of this consider the following: there are 4! (24) arrangements of the 4 digits. There are 10 choose 4 (210) ways to select the 4 unique digits. So 5040 of the 10000 numbers have 4 unique digits. Once you have the 4 unique digits you have a 1/24 chance of guessing correctly (then 1/23, 1/22, so on as you continue guessing). As long as you don't repeat guesses there is no "smart way" to guess them. So once you are through the first phase, it should take 12.5 guesses on average more in this case.

3 unique digits (e.g. 1223)- there are 4!/2=12 unique arrangements of 3 unique digits with a duplicated digit. There are 10 choose 3 (120) ways to select 3 unique digits, but since one of them is duplicated, we need to multiple by 3 to consider all possibilities (360). So 4320 of the 10000 numbers have 3 unique digits. Once you know the digits you have a 1/12 chance of guessing correctly.So it should take 6.5 guesses on average in this case.

1 unique digit (e.g. 0000) -probability of this is 10/10000=1/1000. In the first phase, it will take 5.5 guesses on average, and then you are done.

2 unique digits (e.g. 1122 or 1112)- From the other cases we have 5040+4320+10=9370 of the cases accounted for. So that means this case makes up the other 630 cases. Let us break this case into two: 3 of the same digit and 1 other or 2 and 2. 3/1: this makes up 90*4=360 of the 630 cases. There are 45 different selections of 2 digits. Once you've figured out the digits there are only 8 ways to arrange them, so it should take 4.5 guesses on average.  2/2: again 45 selections of the 2 digits, and these make up the remaining 270 cases. Once you've got the 4 digits, there are only 6 ways to arrange them so 3.5 guesses on average.

So with this method it will take on average $$[(12.5+C_4)*5040+(6.5+C_3)*4320+(5.5)*10+(4.5+C_2)*360+(3.5+C_2)*270]/10000$$ guesses, where $C_i$ is the average number of guesses it takes to correctly identify i special objects out of 10 (for i=1 it is 5.5). As an approximation, suppose the other $C_i$s were 8. Then we get 17.4 Guesses on average.

Here is a slight improvement to the method. In phase 1: guess 0000. If 2 of those digits are correct, instead of guessing 1111, guess 0011. Then if you have 3 digits correct, next guess 0012 (and so on). Basically you just update so that you aren't making guesses that already know are wrong. This will reduce your number of guesses by 999/1000 (almost 1 guess) on average and reduce your worst case scenario by 1 guess, because the guess that makes you discover the final digit will be a "valid guess" (4 of the digits will be correct), which before only happened if it had exactly 4 of the same number.

If my guess that the $C_i$s are all 8 is close enough, then the answer to your question is 16.4 guesses on average.

Worst case, using my proposed method is 9+24=33 (if they happen to be all unique digits and you have the worst luck).

The $C_i$s can be calculated, but that takes a bit more work. My gut tells me $C_i=10-11/(i+1)$, but my gut could be wrong. 
Using these values we get 15.7177 guesses on average.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood how the game works, you can do much better than existing answers suggest.

First, trying `1111` through `9999` you can deduce how many of each digit there are (you don't need to check `0`s specifically). Now after this I claim you can finish in at most five more goes.

I'll start with the hardest case that all four digits are different, say `1234` in some order. Now using a digit known not to appear you can pin down the position of the `1` in two attempts by trying `1100` and `1010`. This leaves say `x1xx` where the three `x`s are `234` in some order. Now try `2123`. If this matches in three places, the correct answer is either `2143` or `4123`. If it matches in two, the correct answer is `2134` or `3124`. If it only matches one, the correct answer is `3142` or `4132`. So in each case you can get the right answer in at most two more guesses.

If there are three different digits, say they are `1233` in some order, first pin down the location of the `1` in two guesses, as before. Now there are only three possibilities for the other digits, so you can finish in three more guesses.

If there are two pairs, say `1122`, you can work out the first digit by guessing `1000`, and then there are only three possibilities left. Finally, if there are three or four of one digit, there are at most three options so you can easily do it.

This gets the right combination with at most $14$ guesses in the worst case.